# Dictionary.ContainsKey(entry) returns false

Tags: c#

I have a string List that contains some numbers . 
I have some string in mybuylist that matches in Dictionary list. But this if condition always returns False.  Ok mybuylist like [34,45,58] and mcollection(key,value) like this {[565,5]},{[34,1]},{[78,9]}....

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> mcollection = new Dictionary<string, int>();
public static List<string> mybuylist = new List<string>();

foreach (string entry in mybuylist) {

 if (mcollection.ContainsKey(entry))
    {
     //dosomething                     

    }

}
```

Hope someone help me about this

Comment: Obviously, `mcollection` has different keys than what's in `mylist`.

Comment: Show us your full code..

Comment: please share the code

Comment: That means `mcollection` doesn't contain any keys as far as the [used string comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072(v=vs.110).aspx) is concerned.

Comment: Be aware that keys are case sensitive :)

Comment: sory for question is not clear. my list contains some dictionary keys but this always returns false

Comment: @ErdemAlkan The key words were *as far as the [used string comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072(v=vs.110).aspx) is concerned*. Are you expecting the strings to match case-insensitively?

Comment: @ErdemAlkan Why don't you show the contents of "mybuylist" and "mcollection" in your question so it would be clear enough ??

Comment: Ok mybuylist like [34,45,58] and mcollection key,value like this {[565,5]},{[34,1]},{[78,9]}....

Comment: Your code working fine. where the issue is? See my Edit post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the the problem of case-sensitive comparison or Keys are not matching. All Dictionaries are `case-sensitive` by default. `A` and `a` are different. Verify whether the values in `mybuylist` and `mcollection` are same or not.

Declare `mcollection` like below.

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> mcollection = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

This will ignorecase and `A` & `a` are same.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995308/case-sensitive-dictionary-keys).

**EDIT 1**:

```
class Program
{
    public static Dictionary<string, int> mcollection = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "565", 5 }, { "34", 1 }, { "78", 9 } };
    public static List<string> mybuylist = new List<string>() { "34", "45", "58" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string entry in mybuylist)
        {
            if (mcollection.ContainsKey(entry))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry);
                //dosomething                     
            }
        }
    }
}

O/P: 34
```

**EDIT 2**: Use below code to remove the spaces

```
mybuylist = mybuylist.ConvertAll(s => s.Trim());
```

Comment: You don't know that is the reason.

Comment: actualy all the items in mybuylist contains numeric  chars.

Comment: @Yosi what you mean? can you explain.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi - Sure, if you seen the contents of "mybuylist" and "mcollection" then you could realize if that's a problem of case-sensitive comparison, have you seen it?

Comment: @ErdemAlkan update your question and give an example of an item that is contained in "mcollection" and also in "mybuylist"

Comment: i updated question with my list and dictionary values

Comment: Yes i checked your code in different app you right yourr code runs perfect . But something wrong in my code. I initialized mybuylist with sql query that query returns string values. I also initialized my Dictionary list  with parsing some text in my code.  Both lists they have contains some strings matches. But  if condition always return false.  this makes me mad.

Comment: Thank you. i found my mistake  my sqlquery returns list items like      "34     " i didnt realized there was a space char in list items. Gratz

Comment: @ErdemAlkan, Please see my EDIT 2 response.

Comment: Thank you it also helped me. I am sory for the mess.